# Parse file does not yield expected output in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a csv file by **space** as a delimiter However, my java code only picks up the first column value and not the second. Can someone point me my issue ?

CSV File Format

```
DATE TIME ENV ASSIGNED 
2014-07-04 04:05:10  y0 499 
2014-07-04 05:14:09  y0 501 
2014-07-04 06:14:47  y1 505
```

Java Code

```
String csvFile = "C:\\Tools\\parsesqldb\\his_sum.csv";
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = " ";

try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use space as separator
        String[] data= line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        System.out.println("Date Time [date= " + data[1]  + " , time=" + data[2] + "]");

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the result you get and what is the result you expected?

Comment: Do you know what the index of the first element of an array is?

Comment: First of all, CSV stands for comma-separated values, and your file is space delimited.  Second of all, arrays in java start indexing from 0, so your data and time fields in your print statement are wrong. Third of all, splitting on space will give you blank columns, try splitting on `\\s+` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the columns delimiters:

```
2014-07-04 04:05:10  y0 499 
          ^        ^^  ^
          0        1|  3
                    2
```

You'll notice that the column between 1 and 2 is empty, which is why you don't get anything.

If you'd like to accept any number of spaces as delimiter, you can use

```
String cvsSplitBy = " +";
```

The `+` is regex for "one or more occurences". This way, the double space will be considered one delimiter.

Comment: ah i never realized there was an extra space in there till you pointed me to that thanks i will accept your answer. Anynumber of space works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use code something like this:

```
string.split("\\s+")
```

Here, \s+ will take care of any number of spaces >=1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is more simple. The date is in the 0th index of the returned array...try `System.out.println("Date Time [date= " + data[0]  + " , time=" + data[1] + "]");`